# The effectiveness of reading large chunks using fread() and read()

Tags: c, performance, system, fread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [speed comparison between fgetc/fputc and fread/fwrite in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250889/speed-comparison-between-fgetc-fputc-and-fread-fwrite-in-c)

Suppose I wanted to read a large chunk of data by implementing fread() in the following way:

```
FILE *fp;
double * dataBuffer;
int fileSize;

fileSize = 8 * 128 * 500001;
fp = fopen ( "binaryData.dat", "rb" );

dataBuffer = (double*) malloc (fileSize);
fread (dataBuffer,fileSize,1,fp);
fclose (fp);
```

According to

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fread.html

fread() will make *fileSize* calls to fgetc(), in order to store all the data from the file (I'm assuming I know the size of the file before hand) to the buffer (*dataBuffer*). Now according to:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fgetc.html

fgetc() only reads one byte per call. How exactly is fgetc() reading these bytes (one by one)? Does fgetc() at some point perform the system call read() to read in one byte from the file? In other words, is fread() making *fileSize* read() system calls?

I've read that fread() is efficient (or can be used efficiently) because it uses buffered streams. But I can't see how that would make a difference if it still uses read() to read one byte at a time.

I'm more probably not making any sense now but that's because I'm confused about this issue; which is why I'm posting here. Perhaps it would make more sense to also present this snippet

```
FILE *fp;
double * dataBuffer;
int fileSize, fd;

fileSize = 8 * 128 * 500001;
fp = fopen ( "binaryData.dat", "rb" );
fd = fileno(fp);

dataBuffer = (double*) malloc (fileSize);
read(fd, dataBuffer, fileSize);
fclose (fp);
```

In this code, I'm effectively performing the same task but using read() instead. One question I had about this snippet was the read statement in my code; because I'm specifying in the read statement to read *fileSize* bytes, will this result in *fileSize* individual system calls to read one byte, or just one system call to read *fileSize* bytes in one chunk? And is the data directly stored into dataBuffer, or does it get stored into an intermediate OS buffer beforehand then copied into dataBuffer?

Ultimately, what I'm asking is which snippet of code is more efficient to load such a large chunk of data. I know there have been other posts saying in most cases fread is more effective, but I can't really understand why (at least in my situation).

Thanks