# Interpreting data from fread()

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, fwrite, fread

So I am attempting to pass a `.txt` file through my code to have it echo the characters individually into the output. I am running the script like

```
./a.out < testWords.in > myOut.out
```

The crux is this bit here:

```
size_t bytes = fread(buffer. sizeof(char),sizeof(char),stdin);
fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),bytes,stdout);
fflush(stdout);
```

which works fine.

But how can I interpret characters 1 by 1 in an if statement? For example

```
if (bytes == '\n')
```

doesn't trigger on new lines.

EDIT:

getc(stdin) is a much more efficient way to accomplish my task.

Comment: `bytes` doesn't contain the data you read; you'll find that in `buffer[0]`. Since you're reading just one character at a time, you might as well use `getchar`, or `getc`; likewise you can use `putchar` or `putc`.

Comment: `fread(buffer, sizeof(char),sizeof(buffer),stdin);`

Comment: getc is a much more efficient way to do this, thank you Keith Thompson.

Comment: It's not just "more efficient". The fact that you're trying to read single characters from a text file with fread shows that you haven't even read a single chapter of a book on C. Reading a book (and ultimately many books) is the only way you can possibly learn the language. The details can't be spoonfed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to define efficiency, but your code might run faster if you `fread()` a large buffer. See the line of @BLUEPIXY . See also [speed comparison between fgetc/fputc and fread/fwrite in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250889/speed-comparison-between-fgetc-fputc-and-fread-fwrite-in-c)

And your line `if (bytes == '\n')` is quite strange since pixels are in the `buffer`...`bytes` is just the number of elements successfully read. I am sure you meant something like `if(buffer[i]=='\n')`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int count=0;
    int i;
    char buffer[1000];
    size_t bytes=1;
    while(bytes!=0){
        bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char),sizeof(buffer),stdin);

        for(i=0;i<bytes;i++){
            if(buffer[i]=='\n'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),bytes,stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("there were %d lines in your file\n",count);
    return 0;
}
```

I am also quite sure that my answer comes too late to be useful !

Bye,

Francis